# Python using a regex to find start position of a substring

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need to find the position of a substring within a string.

The substring is the characters ",0*" followed by tow characters that are [0-9] or [A-F]
i.e.

```
kdjrnnj,0*B3;,w0l44
       ^^^^^
qui8ecc),0*21qxxcd4))
        ^^^^^
```

The substring is always exactly 5 characters in length.  There are always some number (inknown) of chars before the substring.  There may or may not be chars after the substring.

I'd like to use re.something to find the starting position of my substring within the string.
My regex knowledge is quite poor - if someone could tell me how to do this you'd save me hours of hacking around.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the position? What's the next step?

Comment: Next step is to remove everything after the substring

Comment: you don't need to know the position for that. Just use `re.sub`.

Comment: @RoyHB: So you need  to *keep* the substring, remove everything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [match object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects)'s `start()` method:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r',0\*[0-9A-F]{2}')
>>> m = r.search("kdjrnnj,0*B3;,w0l44")
>>> if m : print m.start()
7
>>> m = r.search("qui8ecc),0*21qxxcd4))")
>>> if m : print m.start()
8
```

> Next step is to remove everything after the substring

You don't need index for that, that can be done with regex too:

```
>>> strs = "qui8ecc),0*21qxxcd4))"
>>> re.search(r'.*?,0\*[0-9A-F]{2}', strs).group()
'qui8ecc),0*21'

>>> m = r.search("kdjrnnj,0*B3;,w0l44")
>>> if m : print m.group()
kdjrnnj,0*B3
```

`re.search` is **faster** than `re.sub` here:

```
>>> strs = 'kdjrnnj,0*B3;,w0l44'
>>> %timeit r.search(strs).group()
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.42 us per loop
>>> %timeit pattern.sub('', strs)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.79 us per loop

>>> strs = 'kdjrnnj,0*B3;,w0l44'*1000
>>> %timeit r.search(strs).group()
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 us per loop
>>> %timeit pattern.sub('', strs)
10000 loops, best of 3: 59.9 us per loop

>>> strs = 'kdjrnnj'*1000 + ',0*B3;,w0l44'
>>> %timeit r.search(strs).group()
1000 loops, best of 3: 260 us per loop
>>> %timeit pattern.sub('', strs)
1000 loops, best of 3: 410 us per loop
```

Comment: Cool; the lookbehind kills it for my version. It'd be interesting to see if the OP needs to *retain* the pattern; if not, then `re.search()` would need a look-ahead or group and then `re.sub()` might win it again, or perhaps `re.split()` would be the better option even.

Answer (score 0):

Python `re.search()` returns a [`MatchObject()` instance](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) when a match is made, it includes a `.start()` method to give you the matched position:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r',0\*[0-9A-F]{2}')

match = pattern.search(inputstring)
if match:
    print match.start()
```

Note the `\*` though; an asterisk (`*`) is a regular expression metacharacter, so it needs to be escaped with a slash to match a literal `*`.

The `[0-9A-F]` defines a character class that matches any character in the two named ranges, and the `{2}` following the class limits it to matching *exactly* two characters.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r',0\*[0-9A-F]{2}')
>>> match = pattern.search('kdjrnnj,0*B3;,w0l44')
>>> match.start()
7
>>> match.group()
',0*B3'
>>> match = pattern.search('qui8ecc),0*21qxxcd4))')
>>> match.start()
8
>>> match.group()
',0*21'
```

If you need to remove everything *after* this string, use `re.sub()` instead:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=,0\*[0-9A-F]{2}).*')

newstring = pattern.sub('', oldstring)
```

This uses a look-behind assertion; it looks for your pattern, then matches everything that *follows*, and the `re.sub()` call then removes what was matched from the inputstring.

Demo:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=,0\*[0-9A-F]{2}).*')
>>> pattern.sub('', 'kdjrnnj,0*B3;,w0l44')
'kdjrnnj,0*B3'
>>> pattern.sub('', 'qui8ecc),0*21qxxcd4))')
'qui8ecc),0*21'
```

Note how everything after `,0*B3` and `,0*21` is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

The regex for this should be pretty simple: `.*,0\*[0-9A-F]{2}`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.search()`:

`re.search(r',0*[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]', your_string).start()`